# Show zero value in sum column in query of multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sum column "Sum(Material_Location.On_Hand_Qty)Stock" in my query of multiple tables in which I have joined together.  However, if there is no stock or zero qty, no row or data shows up in the query.  How can I still get row or data to show up as zero on hand qty?  Stuck please help.

```
SELECT (Material_Location.Material) Part, Material.Description,
    SUM(Material_Location.On_Hand_Qty) Stock,  
    (Material.Order_Point)MinTarget, (Material.Stocked_UofM)Unit, 
    (Job.In_Production_Quantity)InProductionQty,
    Material.Class, (SO_Detail.Order_Qty)OnOrderQty
FROM PRODUCTION.dbo.Material Material,
     PRODUCTION.dbo.Material_Location Material_Location
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Job.Part_Number, Sum(In_Production_Quantity) In_Production_Quantity 
          FROM PRODUCTION.dbo.Job Job 
          Where Job.Status = 'Active' 
          Group by Job.Part_Number
          )Job on Job.Part_Number = Material_Location.Material
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SO_Detail.Material, Sum(Order_Qty) Order_Qty 
           FROM PRODUCTION.dbo.SO_Detail SO_Detail 
           Where SO_Detail.Status = 'Open' 
           Group by SO_Detail.Material
          )SO_Detail on SO_Detail.Material = Material_Location.Material
WHERE Material.Material = Material_Location.Material 
      AND Material.Material In ('xxxxxx', 'xxxxx')
GROUP BY Material_Location.Material, Material.Description, 
         Material.Order_Point, Material.Stocked_UofM, 
         Job.In_Production_Quantity, Material.Class, 
         SO_Detail.Order_Qty
```

Comment: `coalesce(sum(column), 0)`.

Comment: Tried this and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are summing a value from the _Material_Location_ table which you are doing an INNER JOIN on (ie, you have used the old join syntax using a comma).

Changing that to a LEFT OUTER JOIN should solve that issue:-

```
SELECT Material_Location.Material AS Part, 
        Material.Description,
        Material.Order_Point AS MinTarget, 
        Material.Stocked_UofM AS Unit, 
        Job.In_Production_Quantity AS InProductionQty,
        Material.Class, 
        SO_Detail.Order_Qty AS OnOrderQty,
        SUM(Material_Location.On_Hand_Qty AS Stock
FROM PRODUCTION.dbo.Material Material
LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODUCTION.dbo.Material_Location Material_Location ON Material.Material = Material_Location.Material 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT Job.Part_Number, 
            Sum(In_Production_Quantity) In_Production_Quantity 
    FROM PRODUCTION.dbo.Job Job 
    WHERE Job.Status = 'Active' 
    GROUP BY Job.Part_Number
)Job ON Job.Part_Number = Material_Location.Material
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT SO_Detail.Material, 
            SUM(Order_Qty) Order_Qty 
    FROM PRODUCTION.dbo.SO_Detail SO_Detail 
    WHERE SO_Detail.Status = 'Open' 
    GROUP BY SO_Detail.Material
)SO_Detail on SO_Detail.Material = Material_Location.Material
WHERE Material.Material In ('xxxxxx', 'xxxxx')
GROUP BY Material_Location.Material, 
        Material.Description, 
        Material.Order_Point, 
        Material.Stocked_UofM, 
        Job.In_Production_Quantity, 
        Material.Class, 
        SO_Detail.Order_Qty
```

Note that mixing the old style implicit join syntax with the newer explicit join syntax is generally a bad idea. There can be odd issues resulting from the difference in precedence between the different types of join.

Comment: @user6559135 - Can you post the table declares and enough sample data to recreate the problem, then we have a chance of finding a solution

Comment: Kickstart, not sure I know what you mean?  Sorry haven't been coding for very long.  I am picking the part numbers ('xxxxx', 'xxxxx') I want and the first part number comes up but the second one does not because it has a zero qty on hand in the column "Material_Location.On_Hand_Qty".

Comment: @user6559135 - If you export the table declares (ie, in phpmyadmin go to export and do so), then it will give the code needed to create a table. Also export a bit of data, with enough rows to recreate the issue. Then I (or others) can create example tables on our own databases and test any solution we have. But what is needed is a change to a LEFT OUTER JOIN which my code has (along with a type I am just fixing!)